# different results when using /.../ and RegEx with exec

Tags: javascript, regex

Why is this different?

```
var addressValue = "http://partners.webmasterplan.com/click.asp?ref=755891&site=8883&type=text&tnb=2&diurl=http://www.redcoon.de/B440080-Tefal-FV-9640_B%C3%BCgeleisen";
var reAffilinet = new RegExp("diurl=[(http|https):\/\/]*w*\.*([a-z]*)");
reAffilinet.exec(addressValue); 
// ["diurl=http://www.redcoon.de/B440080-Tefal-FV-9640_B%C3%BCgeleisen", ""]
```

From this:

```
var addressValue = "http://partners.webmasterplan.com/click.asp?ref=755891&site=8883&type=text&tnb=2&diurl=http://www.redcoon.de/B440080-Tefal-FV-9640_B%C3%BCgeleisen";
var reAffilinet = /diurl=[(http|https):\/\/]*w*\.*([a-z]*)/;
reAffilinet.exec(addressValue); 
// ["diurl=http://www.redcoon.de/B440080-Tefal-FV-9640_B%C3%BCgeleisen", ""]
```

As far as i understood this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions they should be the same...?

Comment: when you write a pattern in a quoted string you must escape the backslashes. `\.` => `\\.` (and don't escape the slashes since there are no more delimiters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convenient property of regex literals is you don't have to escape the `\`.

If you want to use the RegExp constructor, this escaping is necessary in order to define the [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation):

```
var reAffilinet = new RegExp("diurl=[(http|https):\\/\\/]*w*\\.*([a-z]*)");
```